# Download a file from Access Database to Local PC using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2010

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class VirtualStorage

    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\Safevault.accdb")


    Dim dr, dr2 As OleDbDataReader



    Private Sub btnbrow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnbrow.Click
        Dim OFP As New OpenFileDialog

        OFP.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|txt files (*.txt)|*.txt"

        OFP.ShowDialog()

        txtfilepath.Text = OFP.FileName



    End Sub

      
    Private Sub ReadData()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM filestorage WHERE username = @id", conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = x
        conn.Open()
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            DGVSV.Rows.Add(dr.Item("id").ToString,
                           dr.Item("filename").ToString,
                                dr.Item("filedata"))
        End While
        conn.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btndownload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btndownload.Click
        DownloadData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DownloadData()
        Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM filestorage WHERE ID = @id", conn)
        Dim i, j As Integer
        i = DGVSV.CurrentRow.Index
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGVSV.Item(0, i).Value

        conn.Open()

        dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader

        While dr2.Read

            Dim fileBytes As Byte() = DirectCast(dr2.Item("filedata"), Byte())

        End While
        conn.Close()


    End Sub

End Class
```

DGVSV = DataGridView

So I have uploaded several files into my database. Now I would like to download these files back to my local pc from the database. How to do that?

In the database these files are saved as long binary data type.

I have uploaded my whole set of codes. Have a look at it. U can see that the extension i have set to aLL type of files.

Comment: `Dim fileBytes As Byte() = DirectCast(dr.Item("filedata"), Byte())`. Did you also save the file extension, or the file name (which includes the extension)? Are you sure `ID` is a string? Why are you selecting all Fields when you read just one? Also, `cmd2.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGVSV(0, DGVSV.CurrentRow.Index).Value?.Tostring()`, in case it's actually a string Type. -- Where did you declared the Connection? You should create and open it in the same procedure, then dispose of it.

Comment: No i did not save the file extension or the file path or the file name. I just uploaded the file alone. Also it can search the particular row of data. That i'm sure because i tried retrieving other column of data it can read. But i'm not sure how to download a file that has been saved in my database

Comment: If you didn't save at least the extension, how do you know how to save the file? What extension(s) are you specifying? Are all files in the same format (e.g., all Word Documents, all PNG Images)? Are you determining the file type by the binary signature? -- Where is `dr2` coming from? This is undeclared (and you're then using a non-existing `dr` reference). Post real code.

Comment: I have posted the real code above.

Comment: You're not downloading a file. There is no file. You're simply querying the database to get binary data. Once you have a `Byte` array in your app then you can save it to a file the same way you would for any `Byte` array, so that is what you need to research how to do.

Comment: Once you have the data, in `fileBytes`, you just need `File.WriteAllBytes()`. The problems listed above (and more in this update) remain. + What file name you will assign to these files is up to you. You should save the original file name or at least its extension. Unless all files are of the same type or you're reading the signature (because you only store a limited set of file types, so you only need a limited set of signatures). -- Trying to store the Connection object with OleDb and a MS-Access database is really really not recommended.

Comment: Review https://lebans.com/oletodisk.htm

Comment: How about sharing the code where you added the file to the database. It might give us a clue about how to retrieve it.